# How to append DOM element of type button in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

How do I append new buttons, with modified values using a for loop? I have used the `createElement` attribute to create the button.

```js
var par=document.getElementById("numfield");
var ch=document.createElement("INPUT");
ch.setAttribute("type","button");
ch.setAttribute("value","1");
par.appendChild(ch);
```

Comment: Please make sure you upload working code snippets.

Comment: Also, please try something first. This is not a get code for free site; you need to try to solve the problem first. (If you did try, then sorry. The answer was simple enough that I assumed you didn't try (no offense).)

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing the value and id of the button every time you add a new one. Note that this works without adding an id, too, but this allows you to access the buttons more easily.

```js
var par=document.getElementById("numfield");
for(var i=0; i<10; i++){
var ch=document.createElement("INPUT");
ch.setAttribute("type","button");
ch.setAttribute("value",i);
ch.setAttribute("id",i);
par.appendChild(ch);
}
```

```html
<div id="numfield">
</div>
```